# How to merge the changes of fileA with fileB while also overwriting the changes of fileA with changes in fileB

Tags: python, bash, git, git-merge

I have a use case where I am replicating the same code in a few files, so what I'd like to do is create a common file with the base code while all the other files inherit the same code from the base file and some.

- Whatever overwrites I would have in the derived file should be overwritten on the basefile
- Additions of base file should be included
- Additions of derived file should also be included

Edit:
[This might be one of the ways to do merging of two files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63425/how-to-use-patch-and-diff-to-merge-two-files-and-automatically-resolve-conflicts) but then this didn't help much, I still would have to manually go about deleting and keep what I wanted, I would like to automate the process. I'm thinking using `diff` or `sdiff` would be helpful? But these are interactive so how would we automate it?

Eg:

**base.py**

```py
def basefunc1(a, b):
    c = a + b
    return c

def basefunc2(a):
    b = a**2
    return b
```

**derived.py**

```py
def derivedfunc(a, b):
    c = a + b
    return c

def basefunc2(a, b):
    c = a**b
    return c
```

**output.py**

```py
def basefunc1(a, b):
    c = a + b
    return c

def basefunc2(a, b):
    c = a**b
    return c

def derivedfunc(a, b):
    c = a + b
    return c
```

Here `basefunc1(a, b)` and `derivedfunc(a, b)` are unique and should be included in the output, but `basefunc2(a, b)` was edited in the derived file so that should be written to the output. Basically in `diff` when `derived` is compared with `base`, deletions in base(wrt derived) and additions in derived(wrt base) should be additions in output, but changes in derived(wrt base) should be overwritte.

My approach:

What I thought would work was:

```bash
git diff --no-index file1.py file2.py | grep '^+' | sed 's/^+//' | sed '/^++/d'
```

using this I would find the changed part, but then I would have to do this twice, since this only gives the addition and changes of the derived file, the second time would be comparing this and the base file to get the unique elements of the first file.

I also tried

```bash
git merge-file file1.py file2.py file3.py
```

Merging into file1 of file2 wrt empty file3, but then I couldn't figure out how to remove all the lines from `<<<<<<<<` to `========` since those would be the current change which I would like to replace with the incoming change, but I'd also like to keep the unique current change of the current file while also keeping the unique incoming changes.

Comment: if you know what the final result should be, just put that as the file contents

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now, but I have the same code common among more than 10 files, hence the idea to put the common code in a single file and only the changes in the other file and merge them

Comment: oh, practically any time the same code exists in multiple places consider consolidating it!

Comment: I could, but these files are independent of each other, perform different functions, but have the same code structure with some differences. 

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this python script to do what you require.  Based on your example files, it works.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import importlib
import os
import sys

from inspect import getmembers, isfunction, getsource

if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print("ERROR: must have 3 arguments.")
    print("       file 1: base file.")
    print("       file 2: derived file.")
    print("       file 3: output file.")
    exit
else:
    # files to process
    file1 = str(sys.argv[1])
    file2 = str(sys.argv[2])
    outfile = str(sys.argv[3])

    # import sees packages without the extension
    modulename1 = os.path.splitext(file1)[0]
    modulename2 = os.path.splitext(file2)[0]

    # load both modules
    module1 = importlib.import_module(modulename1, package=None)
    module2 = importlib.import_module(modulename2, package=None)

    # get a set of functions in file1
    functions1 = getmembers(module1, isfunction)
    functionsset1 = set([i[0] for i in functions1])
    print(functionsset1)
    # {'basefunc1', 'basefunc2'}

    # get a set of functions in file2
    functions2 = getmembers(module2, isfunction)
    functionsset2 = set([i[0] for i in functions2])
    print(functionsset2)
    # {'basefunc2','derivedfunc'}

    # Empty the output file
    open(outfile, 'w').close()

    # Write the functions into the outfile
    with open(outfile, "a") as outputfile:

        # 1- functions only in file1
        #    print these directly to the output file
        functionsdifflist1 = list(functionsset1.difference(functionsset2))
        print(functionsdifflist1)
        for f in functionsdifflist1:
            objectname = 'module1.' + str(f)
            outputfile.write(getsource(eval(str(objectname))))

        # 2- functions only in file2
        #    print these directly to the output file
        functionsdifflist2 = list(functionsset2.difference(functionsset1))
        print(functionsdifflist2)
        for f in functionsdifflist2:
            objectname = 'module2.' + str(f)
            outputfile.write(getsource(eval(str(objectname))))

        # 3- functions present in both
        #    print the version from file2
        functionsintersectlist = list(functionsset1.intersection(functionsset2))
        print(functionsintersectlist)
        # basefunc2
        for f in functionsintersectlist:
            objectname = 'module2.' + str(f)
            outputfile.write(getsource(eval(str(objectname))))
```

---

How to use it: `./script.py base.py derived.py output.py`

What it does:

- load the functions from base.py
- load the functions from derived.py
- builds a set of all functions from base.py
- builds a set of all functions from derived.py
- uses set functions to calculate differences and intersection
- functions that are just in base.py are sent directly to output.py
- functions that are just in derived.py are sent directly to output.py
- for functions that are in both, take the version from derived.py

Disclaimers:

- I did not do a full `try: catch:` script, it might fail in some situations.
- this code was only tested with files in the same directory as the script.
- I used `eval` which is frowned upon in certain circles.  It was the only way I found to store the name of an object in a variable for function `getsource`.
- the output file is overwritten.  If it already contains something it will be lost.
- you can comment the debug `print` statements, I used these to work on the code.